# Run configuration for a PHP project

Tags: php, eclipse

I have already downloaded PDT, and want to run a `Hello World` in PHP in Eclipse. But I have got the following error. I guess it must be related to `Run Configuration`, could anyone tell me how to fix it?

Otherwise, should I download something else (e.g. XAMPP)?

[image]

Comment: Eclipse does not come with a built-in PHP interpreter. Just install XAMPP. And make you sure you create a seperate workspace for your PHP projects inside the document root. Then all you have to do, is start Apache, and view the page in the browser.

Comment: Or you can use UniserverXI which is about as easy a PHP mysql setup you could ask for, in fact it will run off a flash stick if you want.

Comment: wamp is another good package, do give this a try too.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a portal number? 
like localhost:8080/Coffee/index.php
Try adding a portal number and you can also test it on your browser. Hope it helps!